Record Limit using SQL INSERT Statements to SQL Server via ADO in VBA
I'm trying to insert multiple records into an Azure SQL Server database. I am building an SQL string containing multiple 'INSERT' statements for the records I wish to add. These statements are in the form;
INSERT INTO Table (ID, DataRow, RowValue) VALUES (211, 30, 0.398664208000758) 
INSERT INTO Table (ID, DataRow, RowValue) VALUES (212, 22, 0.458785695831563) 
...

I am then opening a connection and executing the sql;
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
con.ConnectionString = [ConnectionString]
con.CursorLocation = adUseServer
con.Open
con.Execute sql

This runs without any errors but will only ever add 322 records.
If I take the entire string of INSERT statements and paste them into a query in SQL Server Management Studio, all the records are added to the database without any errors.
Thanks in advance for taking a look and any suggestions greatly appreciated.

What happens if you use this syntax: INSERT INTO Table (ID, DataRow, RowValue) VALUES (211, 30, 0.398664208000758) ,  (212, 22, 0.458785695831563);

I think the INSERT VALUES has a limit of 1000 values when inserting like this.

May be waiting for you to consume the row count messages.  Try adding SET NOCOUNT ON to the beginning of the batch.

Thanks very much David Browne - that worked. Would you like to add your suggestion as an answer?

The solution (as suggested by David Browne) is to include 'SET NOCOUNT ON' at the start of the sql statement.
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO Table (ID, DataRow, RowValue) VALUES (211, 30, 0.398664208000758) 
INSERT INTO Table (ID, DataRow, RowValue) VALUES (212, 22, 0.458785695831563) 
...

